# Working Around the OS X Catalina Conflict with Emacs 26.3

Tags: python, osx, emacsclient, bash

I'm struggling to workaround the problem discussed in [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53248/finder-of-macos-catalina-cannot-open-a-file-with-emacs). I'm working through the accepted solution (which also references [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/239231/osx-open-with-bash-script/239235#239235), and getting what I *think* is close, but not quite there. The steps I'm taking—-just to try to recap my integration of multiple SO posts--are:

Putting the following script into a file called `emacs_catalina_wrapper`, which now resides in my Laptop-level `Applications` folder (i.e. *not* my user-level `Applications` folder). That script (shell set to `/bin/bash`, which is what I'm using in Terminal) is exactly:

```sh
if ! pgrep Emacs; then
    open -a Emacs.app
    sleep 1
fi
for f in "$@"
do
    /usr/local/bin/emacsclient -cn -d localhost:0 "$f"
done
```

(I added `-d localhost:0` because I was otherwise getting the error discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626841/emacsclient-could-not-get-terminal-name).)

I then run the following from terminal:

```
MyMac:bin$open -a /Applications/emacs_catalina_wrapper.app my_python_script.py
```

Whether or not Emacs is already running, that brings up a *blank* window (which *appears* to bear the name of that script, but contains none of its text -- my_python_script.py is not new...it's an existing script I'm looking to *edit*, not create). my_python_script.py lives in the directory I'm running this from, btw.

What am I missing? I'm not even sure what additional information to add here to help you help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, whelp, [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/12/12/fixing-emacs-macos-catalina/) got me around that, and was a lot less work too!