# Fix Catalina crash when clicking on File > Open or the Open button on the Toolbar

Tags: osx

I'm on macOS Catalina, and I'm using [Emacs for Mac OS X](https://emacsformacosx.com). When I click File > Open, or the Open button on the toolbar, or "Open a File" on the splash screen, I get a crash.

I have tried some other Emacs distributions, namely:

- `emacs --with-cocoa` installed via Homebrew
- `emacs-plus` installed via Homebrew

I have granted file system access to the various executables for each distribution, and all three options give the same errors.

Here's the part of the crash report that I think is most helpful:

```
Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectNotAvailableException',
reason: 'EmacsSavePanel is not a supported subclass for sandboxing'
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

From the crash report, I thought the problem was with file system access. I followed the steps in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53026/how-to-restore-file-system-access-in-macos-catalina/53037#53037), but giving `/usr/bin/ruby` full disk access did not fix the problem. I've also tried giving the following full disk access, but so far no success:

- The Emacs app
- the `Emacs` executable inside the Emacs app
- The Homebrew install of Ruby (both `/usr/local/bin/ruby` and `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/bin/ruby`

Is there something else I should be looking for?

Comment: I suggest to use Homebrew to install ```emacs-plus``` from this site: https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus. That does not exhibit such problem. Further, when opening and accessing, IIRC, will ask for giving permission, and the results will be shown in Setting -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> File and Folders. If not, manually add Emacs there (I do not remember to do it manually in my case...).

Comment: Thanks Ian. I have tried `emacs-plus`, the "regular" `emacs` via Homebrew, and `emacs --with-cocoa`, which appears to just download the [Emacs for Mac OS X](https://emacsformacosx.com) package. All give the same result. None ask for permission and adding permission manually via Settings > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access does not fix the issue either. I will add some of this info to my question.