# pdb hangs through gud on emacs when path has `@` symbol

Tags: gud

### more tests

I've now confirmed this behavior in Emacs 24.5 on a linux machine. Basically, if there is an `@` symbol in one of the parent directories, gud will hang.

### the first update

I've actually discovered what the issue is, but don't know how to fix it.

My current laptop is a company issued laptop and my username/home directory is defined like so: `/Users/myname@mycompany.com/`

If the python file I'm debugging with gud/pdb is under that path, pdb fails to launch properly. Any other path, and it launches fine.

So I'm guessing that `@` symbol is the source of the current problems.

Is there any way to modify some variable or gud so that it can work with that `@` symbol in the path?

### the original post

I'm not even sure how to even begin to debug or diagnose this issue. And searching turns up nothing.

Basically, `M-x pdb` will create a buffer and display `Current directory is XYZ` and then just stop there.

I've used `M-x pdb` successfully many times in the past but I recently switched to MacOS Catalina and also updated emacs to 26.3. I installed python 3.7.7 via homebrew.

Here's what I've tried so far

- disable .emacs
- use homebrew emacs
- use the emacs at emacsformacosx.com
- update python from 3.7.3 to 3.7.7
- remove all python packages

None of them work. And it's not a pdb issue because I can enter pdb fine from any regular shell. I just can't get pdb through gud.

Is there a solution? Or is there a way I can at least debug the gud/pdb launch process?

Comment: Is it the new catlalina privacy permissions? https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53026/how-to-restore-file-system-access-in-macos-catalina

Comment: @al0 Apparently not. I've updated the question with more info.

Comment: Any idea whether this is specific to Emacs 26? If not, i.e., if this is not really a question about Emacs 26 (versus other releases), then please consider removing that tag.

Comment: @Drew I tested it out with Emacs 25 and still the same problem. So tag is removed.

Comment: I observe the same behavior with emacs 26.3 on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @Drew Dunno about `gud`, but apparently `thing-at-point` doesn't recognize @ as part of `'filename` or `'url`. I haven't digged enough into this issue to know if it's a problem from `thing-at-point` or lies beneath it. I noticed the problem trying to use it to recognize/handle tramp-like urls, then realized that same happens with filenames. bounds are up to the @ character.

Comment: Consider filing an enhancement request (`M-x report-emacs-bug`), if you think thing-at-point's handling of file names needs to be enhanced/fixed.