# C-x C-f, Cannot complete file name for desktop folders

Tags: osx, find-file

I am new to Emacs. I am trying to access a file in the `"Emacs"` folder on my desktop.

I run the `C-x C-f` command, then type `~/Desktop/Em`.

I then hit `TAB`, but there's no completion. Emacs says `[No Match]`.

Could someone please explain why the file name doesn't complete? I am working on Mac OS 10.15.6.

[image]

Comment: Why is there a forward slash `/` before your `~`? Try removing that and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, the forward slash is put in by Emacs automatically. The screenshot works if I manually complete the path (i.e. type in ~/Desktop/Emacs)

Comment: The `/` is provided by Emacs because you are in the root directory (`/`). But that shouldn't prevent completion: Emacs will complete `/~/whatever` the same way it completes `~/whatever`.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, do you have a subdirectory `Desktop` in your home directory (`~`)? And do you have a file `Emacs` in that subdirectory?

Comment: Emacs -Q seems to fix the issue! What is going on? Is there a way to make this default behaviour?

Comment: Ok @Drew, I managed to fix it: Seems to be a permission issue:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371888/restore-access-to-file-system-for-emacs-on-macos-catalina

Comment: The `/` at the beginning of the path is a side effect of how MacOS starts applications: when you start Emacs as an application, it doesn't get a working directory set, and defaults to the root directory. When you start it from the terminal (with or without `-Q`), it gets the working directory from the terminal.

Comment: @finite_diffidence: Please post your solution as an answer. (You can accept your own answer.) Q & A need to stand on their own, to help others. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Restore File System Access in macOS Catalina](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53026/how-to-restore-file-system-access-in-macos-catalina)

Answer (score 0):

Following from Drew's response (which also works). I found another answer that solved my issue using Emacs from the Mac launcher bar:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371888/restore-access-to-file-system-for-emacs-on-macos-catalina