# Emacs won’t access Documents directory on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: debugging, osx, files, directories, permissions

I am running Emacs 26.3 on MacOS 11.2.1 “Big Sur”.  When I try to open the directory ~/Documents, it fails with the message “Listing directory failed but ‘access-file’ worked.”   Emacs.app is given Full Disk Access in my System Preferences.  I can open other directories, but not Documents, Downloads, or Desktop.

However, the problem does not occur if I start Emacs not by launching it from the Dock but by opening it from the Terminal with:

/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS
./Emacs

Any ideas about why this is happening and how to fix it?  If I launch it from the terminal I get a couple of error messages:

2021-03-07 16:49:59.308 Emacs-x86_64-10_14[5820:4969143] Failed to initialize color list unarchiver: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver}
2021-03-07 16:50:24.499 Emacs-x86_64-10_14[5820:4969143] TSM AdjustCapsLockLEDForKeyTransitionHandling - _ISSetPhysicalKeyboardCapsLockLED Inhibit

but Emacs seems to work just fine.

My folders are not synched to the Cloud.

Comment: Are you running the Emacs from emacsformacosx.com? If you are, that version has both the Emacs app and also a ruby wrapper around Emacs, and you'll have to grant access to the ruby wrapper as described [in this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53026/how-to-restore-file-system-access-in-macos-catalina/53037#53037).

However, the error you're seeing is different from errors I've seen before so the ruby wrapper may be unrelated.

Comment: I think you're saying that the access-denial occurs regardless of whether you use Dired, so I replace tag `dired` by tag `directories`. If it is truly Dired related then please add back tag `dired`. But in that case please say something in the question about the Dired relation. Thx.

Comment: Thanks amitp.   That solved the problem.   First, I had to find ruby, but with a bit of detective work I was able to figure out that it was in /usr/bin/