# Restore privileged folder access for previously working Emacs.app on Catalina (NOT system upgrade)

Tags: osx, files, find-file, gui-emacs, permissions

This is similar to [How to Restore File System Access in macOS Catalina](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53026/how-to-restore-file-system-access-in-macos-catalina) but the problem is different. I did not upgrade my operating system, only the app, and none of the solutions there are valid fixes for this question.

I am having a problem with my `Emacs.app` on Mac OS X 10.15 Catalina. The distribution i am using is from the emacs-app-devel port from MacPorts.

I initially installed `Emacs.app` on Catalina. Everything worked as expected. When i tried to access privileged locations like `~/Documents`, i received an OS popup asking for permission, granted, and was able to use the app normally.

I then upgraded my `Emacs.app` through macports. After the new install and relaunching, i could no longer access the files using the emacs find-file functionality (default `C-x C-f`). I can still access everything using `File->Open`. Opening a file in one of the protected directories like ~/Documents using `File -> Open` or `ns-open-file-using-panel` does NOT restore access and allow find-file to proceed. Permissions like `"Files and Folders"` `"Network Volumes"` are already granted and i can see them. `Full Disk Access` is not necessary to allow emacs to access these files in Catalina.

Comment: Drew: I meant both find-file and using the keybinding. I have updated the question for clarity, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Investigating this problem, i was able to see a Console.app error from process tccd, (i think this is the "Transparency Consent and Control System" daemon). The error was `Failed to copy signing info for 95201, responsible for file:///Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs: #-67062: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67062 "(null)"`. I do not know if the old install of the app produced by macports was codesigned, but the new one definitely was not (i checked this using `codesign -vvv Emacs.app`). I do not yet know if there will be any unintended side effects, but ah-hoc codesigning the existing app (identity below is '-') did fix my problem.

I used to following command in the app's parent directory:

`sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - ./Emacs.app`

The codesign ran sucessfully, and upon relaunch i was prompted by the OS when i tried to access ~/Documents using find-file. I granted access and was able to open files inside.

The prompt for ~/Documents looked like this: [image: Documents Prompt]